# Organize RubyMine favorites as links rather than subtrees

Tags: rubymine

In RubyMine 6.0.3 when some folder is added to favorites, it appears in favorites as a subtree. I am interested in a not expandable link which leads me to corresponding source folder when double clicked. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible?

Unfortunately No -- it was not designed to work this way.

But ... with **favourite folder** you can use <kbd>Ctrl+F1, 1</kbd> (`Navigate | Select In... | Project View`) instead of clicking on it to select and focus that location in Project View panel.

---

Instead of adding that folder to a Favourites list ... **use Bookmarks**.

Yes -- just bookmark a folder in Project View panel (<kbd>F11</kbd> -- `Navigate | Bookmarks | Toggle Bookmark`). When you click on such bookmark .. IDE will locate and focus that folder in Project View panel for you.